# How can I set the email for a Team with Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, graph-api-explorer

We are creating a team group (with the beta Graph API) and we want the emailaddress to contain another value than the value that's based on what's provided in `displayName`.

While searching through the documentation it seems that this is possible by providing a value for `mailNickname` in `AdditionalData` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-create-group-and-team).

So I implemented that. Unfortunately the mailaddress and the alias were still like `TestGroup@domain.nl` instead of `TestMailNickname@domain.nl`.

```
var graphApiServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(this.authenticationProvider)
{
    BaseUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta"
};

var owner = "valueForOwner";
var teamTemplate = teamTemplateType == TeamTemplateType.Staff
    ? "educationStaff"
    : "educationClass";

var team = new Team
{
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "template@odata.bind", $"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teamsTemplates('{teamTemplate}')" },
        { "owners@odata.bind", new[]{$"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users('{owner}')"}},
        { "displayName", "TestGroup" },
        { "description", "This is a testgroup" },
        { "mailNickname", "TestMailNickname" }
    }
};

await graphApiServiceClient.Teams.Request().AddAsync(team);
```

The `MailNickname` *does* change when I update the `MailNickname` property afterwards with an update request like `await graphApiServiceClient.Groups[objectId].Request().UpdateAsync(new Group { MailNickname = mailNickname});`.

This is confirmed with a `graphApiServiceClient.Groups[objectId].Request().GetAsync()`

Unfortunately it still shows `TestGroup@domain.nl` as the alias in the admin at https://admin.microsoft.com/AdminPortal/Home#/groups.

**But**, updating the value like this doesn't work for the `Mail` property because it states it's readonly in the update request.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong in my original create/add request?

Plus does anyone know why the old alias value is still shown instead of the updated alias at https://admin.microsoft.com/AdminPortal/Home#/groups?

Comment: Why are you setting these in AdditionalData rather than using the Team properties?

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for your reply. My team object doesn't have a Mail or MailNickname property. When I try to use AddAsync with a GroupRequest where I provide a MailNickname and a team, the response states that a Team cannot be added like this and should instead be created with a following up PATCH request. GroupRequest only shows a GetAsync and an AddAsync, so I then tried to use the TeamRequest AddAsync. But this TeamRequest doesn't show Mail properties. The documentation says to provide it in the body, which I thought corresponded with AdditionalData. So that's how I ended up with this :)

Comment: You likely need the Beta SDK rather than the v1.0 one. The mainstream SDK doesn't include properties/objects that only show up in Graph Beta.

Comment: Ah, of course! I'll give that a try when I'm on it again. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is possible by creating a group via the Graph api first and then using the group ID to create a team for this group.

Create the group via "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups".

```
 {  
    "displayName": "TestGroup",  
    "mailNickname": "TestMailNickname",  
    "mailEnabled": true,  
    "securityEnabled": false,  
    "description": "This is a testgroup",  
    "groupTypes": [  
        "Unified"  
    ],  
    "owners@odata.bind": [  
        "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/OWNEDID"  
    ]  
}
```

Once the group has been made it'll output an ID which you'll then use to create a team via "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/YOURIDHERE/team"

Body would look something like;

```
{  
    "memberSettings": {  
        "allowCreateUpdateChannels": false,
        "allowAddRemoveApps": false,
        "allowCreateUpdateRemoveTabs": false,
        "allowCreateUpdateRemoveConnectors": false  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using an EDU tenant, since you are referencing the particular templates.

I have tested this previously, and the method suggested above will not work with the "EducationClass" template.

The way I got it to work was:

- Create the Team with the template

```html
        $Teamdata = 
            '{
                "displayName":"' + $newteamName + '",
                "description":"' + $newteamName + '",
                "template@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates(\u0027educationClass\u0027)",
                "hideFromOutlookClients":  "true",
                "hideFromAddressLists":  "true",
                        "members":[
                    {
                        "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
                        "roles":[
                        "owner"
                        ],
                        "user@odata.bind":"'+ $DefaultOwnerURL + '"
                    }
                ]
            }'
```

- Wait for the group to be created (usually about 20 seconds)
- patch the group mailnickname

```html
        $Body_SetGroupSDSSettings = 
            '{
                "mailNickname": "' + $newteamMailNickname + '"
                
            }'
```

It isn't perfect, but it is the best way I could find to do this.